# Why User.count inside this block is always zero?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

## **Only the first created user can be an admin.**

I was expecting to achieve that with `user.admin = User.count == 0 ? true : false` inside the `self.from_omniauth(auth)` method, but for some reason, it doesn't matter how many users I have, admin is always set to `true`.

To be sure there are no users:

from **rails console**

```
User.destroy_all
User.count
=> 0
```

**user.rb**

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email     = auth.info.email
    user.password  = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.email     = auth.info.email
    user.image     = auth.info.image
    user.name      = auth.info.name
    user.nickname  = auth.info.nickname
    user.admin     = User.administrator?
  end
end 

def self.administrator?
  count == 0
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    ...   
    t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
  end
```

### Thanks!

#### Now it's working in the expected way, but the initial question is still unanswered.

Even when I don't really like this solution, at least is working now.

Here I'm creating this `user_qty` variable outside the block.

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  user_qty = User.count
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.password  = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.email     = auth.info.email
    user.image     = auth.info.image
    user.name      = auth.info.name
    user.nickname  = auth.info.nickname
    user.admin     = user_qty == 0
  end
end
```

Comment: I think the better approach would be to create an admin user by yourself in db/seeds.rb and then `rake db:seed`

Comment: Thanks, but doing that, if anyone clone the project, they got stuck with the same admin account. I'm trying to do that with real accounts. Another way, could be that the user generate the first account, and then from rails console, just change the admin to true, but once again, that's not the goal here. Thanks again!

Comment: Doesn't count count the Users and you look for the `User.id` or `User.uid` - in the hope the first user has the id 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside of the `first_or_create` block executes within the current scope.  In  [ActiveRecord::Relation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb), the `first_or_create` method calls the `create` method which uses `scoping`:

```
def create(*args, &block)
  scoping { @klass.create(*args, &block) }
end
```

And the `scoping` method says to run within the `current_scope`.

A call to `User.count` within this block is like calling:

```
User.where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).count
```

If you debug with:

```
where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
  puts "current_scope: #{current_scope}"
```

You should see something like:

```
current_scope: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."provider" = '<value1>' AND "users"."uid" = '<value2>'
```

If you wanted to ask for the full count of all users within the `first_or_create` block you can do something like:

```
where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
  ...
  user.admin = User.unscoped.count == 0 ? true : false
```